# Design proposal needed: Enabling menu item from outside JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, file-io, jmenuitem

My Java application mainly lifes within a JFrame object. Its "File" menu has 2 entries "Open" and
"Close". "Close" menu item is disabled. It will be enabled by fileOpenActionPerformed once it
finished parsing file:

```
private void fileOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   // (1) get file from JFileChooser
   // (2) parse Contents
   if(bContentsValid == true) {
      this.fileClose.setEnabled(true);
   }
```

As parsing takes quite a while I'd like to factor it out in a separate thread. Thread should enable
"Close" menu item once finished.

Passing the thread a JMenuItem reference looks like rather bad design to me. Any design suggestion?

NB: I thought of using a wrapping object Holding both the JFrame and the thread reference but this
    breaks most of the code generated by NetBeans IDE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate the on-completion action within a `Runnable` and pass that `Runnable` to your background thread.

This will come handy as, since for a correct implementation, your background thread has to schedule the UI manipulation via [`EventQueue.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) or [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)), you will need a `Runnable` anyway.

---

Alternatively you can implement the entire background activity using a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Then you can override the `done()` method and include the menu item enabling there.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd approach leads to a better design solution. It addressed issue from opposite direction: instead of make thread change GUI --> let GUI have SwingWorker...